# Add to existing older slideshow script to include a caption for images

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, slideshow, caption

I'm wondering if there is a small change or addition I could make to the existing script, to add captions for images in my slideshow, or if I really should just abandon this old script and start fresh. So there are two pages- an intro page and a slideshow page. The intro page has small thumbnail images that when clicked take the visitor to the slideshow page to see the large version of the thumbnail, and from there the visitor can click through all the large thumbnail-representive images or go back to the intro page.

Here's the intro page (relevant part):

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="arbor-viewer-test-files.html?img=0">
     <img src="images/thumbnails/arbor_0.jpg" width="100" />
     </a></td>
    <td><a href="arbor-viewer-test-files.html?img=1">
     <img src="images/thumbnails/arbor_1.jpg" width="100" />
     </a></td>
    <td><a href="arbor-viewer-test-files.html?img=2">
     <img src="images/thumbnails/arbor_2.jpg" width="100" />
     </a></td>
    <td><a href="arbor-viewer-test-files.html?img=3">
     <img src="images/thumbnails/arbor_3.jpg" width="100" />
     </a></td>
    <td><a href="arbor-viewer-test-files.html?img=4">
     <img src="images/thumbnails/arbor_4.jpg" alt="DFW Patio Cover Arbors" border="0" width="100" />
     </a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

And here's the slideshow page (relevant part):

```
<table border="0">
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
              <p class="center largeP bold"> <a href="javascript:chgImg(-1)">Previous</a> | <a href="javascript:auto()">Auto/Stop</a> | <a href="javascript:chgImg(1)">Next</a> <br />
                <a href="/arbors.htm">Return to the Arbor Gallery</a> </p>
              <br />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="center"> <br />
              <img src="images/arbor_0.jpg" name="slideshow" />
              <br />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
showImg(queryString.img);
</script>
</body>
```

And here's the script:

```
var newimg = new Array();
newimg[0] = "images/arbor_0.jpg";
newimg[1] = "images/arbor_1.jpg";
newimg[2] = "images/arbor_2.jpg";
newimg[3] = "images/arbor_3.jpg";
newimg[4] = "images/arbor_4.jpg";

function obj_queryString(){
qs = document.URL.substring(document.URL.indexOf('?')+1,document.URL.length);
queries = qs.split(/\&/);
for(i=0;i<queries.length;i++){ 
    query = queries[i].split(/\=/);
    this[query[0]] = unescape(query[1]);}
 }

queryString = new obj_queryString();
var imgnum = 0;
var imglength = newimg.length - 1;
//delay betwn slides in millisecs
var delay = 3000;
var lock = false;
var run;

function showImg(imgnum){
document.slideshow.src = newimg[imgnum];
}

function chgImg(direction) {
if (document.images){
    imgnum = imgnum + direction;
    if (imgnum > imglength) 
        imgnum = 0;
    if (imgnum < 0) 
        imgnum = imglength;
    document.slideshow.src = newimg[imgnum];}
}

function auto(){
if (lock == true) {
    lock = false;
    window.clearInterval(run);}
else if (lock == false) {
    lock = true;
    run = setInterval("chgImg(1)", delay);}
 }
```

The best I could come up with was adding this to the script:

```
//under the newimg Array:
var caption = new Array();  
caption[0] = "Caption for the first image"; 
caption[1] = "Caption for the second image"; 
caption[2] = "Caption for the third image"; 
caption[3] = "Caption for the fourth image"; 
caption[4] = "Caption for the fifth image";
```

And adding a snippet along with the function at the bottom of the slideshow page (everything else is the same as above):

```
<p id="captionDiv><br /></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
showImg(queryString.img);
document.getElementById("captionDiv").innerHTML=caption[imgnum];
</script>
```

…which just shows caption[0] and doesn't change along with the images. I'm sure the solution is a no-brainer for anyone who knows more javascript than I do.  I've researched and studied up online for over a week and still don't understand what to do. I need a javascript interpreter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put `document.getElementById("captionDiv").innerHTML=caption[imgnum];` inside `function showImg(imgnum)` so that you can get relevent image caption.

Comment: Unfortunately when I put this inside `function showImg(imgnum)`,  "undefined" comes up where the caption should be. Safari's _view source_ says _Failed to load resource: The requested URL is not found on this server._  Also something that might be important is that it considers this "undefined" as resource type:image, but that could just be something with the Safari console.

Comment: thanks for your answer though.  Another thing I've noticed that might be important is the line `var imglength = newimg.length - 1;`.  With this isn't it only referring to the newimg array?  How can I make it refer to both arrays?

Comment: if you are getting undefined then i suspect how slideshow is working. Try debugging your script using developer tools available in browsers.

Comment: So far the debugging tools are not much help. Undefined goes away when `document.getElementById("captionDiv").innerHTML=caption[imgnum];` is placed within the last script right before the closing body tag, but what's displayed is always "Caption for the first image" no matter which thumbnail the user clicks to go to the slideshow or what image they're on when clicking through the slides. Here's the url for the introductory page where you can navigate to the slideshow and back which may help clarify - http://dfwpatiocover.com/arbor-test-page.html. Thanks!

Comment: OK, so the first thumbnail link doesn't work for some reason, but click on any of the others and they take you right through.

Comment: @aman-D all you need to do is put following line in chgImg function document.getElementById("captionDiv").innerHTML=caption[imgnum] after or before document.slideshow.src = newimg[imgnum].

Comment: Its works perfectly fine for me. I don't think you are placing code in proper location.

Comment: If I put it in the function before the closing body tag, I get "Caption for the first image" and it doesn't change with a new picture or reflect which thumbnail the user clicks to go to the slideshow.  If I put it in the function in the head tag, it says "undefined".  Did you get a working example using my source code?

Comment: Yes i have it working using your code. You need to put code in the `chgImg` function in the script in head section, inside if block. There is no reason you can get undefined there.